# Is there a way to update configuration of a running kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a running Kafka debezium connector and now I want to update the values of the following parameters,

```
heartbeat.interval.ms
snapshot.mode
```

Current Config:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
  "database.user": "cdc_user",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "XXX:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "table.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist",
  "database.hostname": "xyzcloud.in",
  "database.password": "ACCSSDD",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace1.fk_sp_generic_checklist.connector",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "database.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
}
```

```
This is what is get:

curl --location --request PUT 'http://XX.XX.7/connectors/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist.connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "abc.cloud.in",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "XXXXX",
        "database.password": "XXXXX",
        "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
        "database.whitelist": "pno",
        "table.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "X9:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
        "errors.tolerance": "all"
    }
}'

Output: {"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}
```

I tried the above mentioned but it gives me method not allowed.

Version:

```
{"version":"6.1.1-ccs","commit":"c209f70c6c2e52ae","kafka_cluster_id":"snBlf-kfTdCYWEO9IIEXTA"}%
```

Answer (score 5):

To update the configuration for an existing connector you can use [`PUT /connectors/(string:name)/config`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#put--connectors-(string-name)-config) method of [Connect REST Interface](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#kconnect-rest-interface).

```sh
curl -XPUT <host>:<port>/connectors/cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace1.fk_sp_generic_checklist.connector/config \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
  "database.user": "cdc_user",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "XXX:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace.fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "table.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist.entity_checklist",
  "database.hostname": "xyzcloud.in",
  "database.password": "ACCSSDD",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.marketplace1.fk_sp_generic_checklist.connector",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "database.whitelist": "fk_sp_generic_checklist",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
}'
```

Comment: {"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}

Comment: Added error in question

Comment: Is that the name which I missed in the curl URL?

Comment: Yes, you have to add connector name to url. Check example I've added

Comment: Thanks for yours help

Comment: Will the connector pick all new updated settings automatically or some action needs to be taken?
How that works?

Comment: Yes, connector tasks will be restarted after configuration upgrade

Comment: There is one case, my connector task is in the failed state due to invalid schema it says, now I have registered a new schema manually in schema registry.
So just doing a restart for the failed task of connector via API work?

Comment: It depends on issue what happened: if it is retriable, then you cat just restart as you said. Keep in mind connector restarting prior 3.0.0 version doesn't affect tasks (check KIP-745 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=181308623)

Comment: ```curl -s --location --request POST "http://10.24.18.167:80/connectors/xyz.connector/restart?includeTasks=true&onlyFailed=true"```
This should work i think.